# The dual space of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ can't be identified as $L_1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

*Let be $C_0(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{K} \ | \ \forall \xi>0 \  \exists K_{\xi} \subset \mathbb{R} \ compact:  \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus K \ |f(x)|<\xi \}$ (or if you prefer $C_0(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{K} \ | \lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty}|f(x)|=0\}$) and $L_1(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{K}\  | \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx<+\infty\}$ where for $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ consider $f$ as an equivalence class $[f]=\{g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{K} \ | \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-g(x)|dx =0\}$.
Proove that $[C_0(\mathbb{R})]^*$ cannot be identified as $L_1(\mathbb{R})$, otherwise, prove that:
$$\exists L\in [C_0(\mathbb{R})]^* \   \nexists f\in L_1(\mathbb{R}):Lg=\int_{\mathbb{R}}fgdx, \ \ g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$$*
$\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R} \ or\ \mathbb{C}$

So as suggested from the exercise, I tried to prove that $Lg=g(0)$ has no $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ as defined, and assuming as an absurd that this $f$ exists I prooved, by using the Lusin theorem on $f$ and the dominated convergence theorem that this would lead to:
$$f(0)=\int_\mathbb{R}f^2dx$$
But I don't know if I could really know if I could use the dominated convergence theorem in this situation because the sequence of functions $f_n$ that the Luisin theorem gives me could not have an upperbound integrable function. The only function for sure that could be an upperbound integrable function for $f_n$ is $f$, but from the Lusin theorem I can conclude that:
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n|\leq\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f|$$
if $f$ is bounded, which I can't know for sure. So I'm stuck, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you know exactly what this $L$ is right? It is the Dirac measure centred at $0$, $\delta_0$. Its action on a continuous function cannot be identified with integration against some $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ simply because $\delta_0$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: "cannot be identified with integration against some $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ simply because $\delta_0$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure." 
Can you please explain with more details this passage?

Comment: If there existed an $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\langle \delta_0,g\rangle=\int f g \, \mathrm{d}x $ for all $g \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ then it would follow that whenever a measurable set $A$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, then $\delta_0(A)=0$. But this is not true because $\delta_0(\{0\})=1$ and $\{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. So this is a contradiction and such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: The closed unit ball in the dual Banach space has extreme points. The unit ball in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ does not admit extreme points.

Comment: @almosteverywhere, I'm sorry but I still don't get it: what is this: $<\delta_0,g>$? Is it $<\delta_0,g>=\int_\mathbb{R}g\delta_0dx$?

Comment: The $\langle\delta_0,g \rangle$ denotes the  action of $\delta_0$ as an element of $[C_0(\mathbb R)]^*$ on $g$. In your notation I guess you could right it as $\delta_0 \, g$

Comment: @almosteverywhere what if I wanted to prove this without using the Dirac measure? Or how can I prove that this $f$ should be $0$?

Comment: @GoofyMushroom0 What do you mean by without using the Dirac measure? The choice of $L$ you have made as a counterexample, i.e. $Lg =g(0)$ is the Dirac measure? Do you want to choose another $L$?